# Magneto 2 not getting custome option price calculation on catalog product view page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js, magento2

I newly start work on magento 2.
I have to active bellow functionality,

http://www.netcurtain2curtains.co.uk/lady-jayne-white-net-curtain-inspired-by-nottingham-lace.html

I was implimenting this functionality 1.9 but i have no idea how to do this in magento2.

Please share your idea with me so I can short it out my problem

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's not really clear. Please explain what you tried, how your code fails, and what are your attempts to fix it. 
Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In magento2 we can set different price for child products of a simple product. So please make 'size' as a product attribute and set different price according to the size.

Comment: How can we achieve using custome option? In older version we playing with JavaScript but in magento2 where and how can we do?